# UTF8 Variable from FLASH Post to filename

Tags: php, flash, post, utf-8, filenames

I am using a script to send a "$filename" variable from flash to PHP in order to create an xml file. The problem is that when I am typing Greek Characters as Filename the filename on the server gets values such as these for example: (Ξ΄ΟƒΟ‰Ξ΄ΟƒΞ±Ο‰Ο‚ΞµΟ‰Ο‚ΞµΞ².qxml)

I do not have any problem a) When writing english characters, b) When writing greek characters data in the xml file.

I am using file_put_contents function.

If instead of getting the Post variable as filename, I set my own filename such as "Ελληνικά.qxml" it works without a problem.

Thanks a lot in advance.

```
$string = $_POST['xmldata'];
$filename = $_POST['filename'];

$path = "test/";

//$dir_handle = @opendir($path) or mkdir("{$path}", 0777, true);

file_put_contents($path."/".$filename."", $string);
```

**This problem was solved, but another arose. When I try to open the file from flash it does not recognise it now because it is in Greek.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that flash is sending the data in different encoding. From the comments in the PHP manual for [mb_convert_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) I can see that you should use the following to get it to work (tested on danisch charactors and not greek)

```
<?php
$string = isset($_POST['xmldata'])?$_POST['xmldata']:"";
$filename = isset($_POST['filename'])?$_POST['filename']:"";

//tested on danish chars
/*
$string = mb_convert_encoding($string, "ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8");
$filename = mb_convert_encoding($filename, "ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8");
*/

//tested on greek chars
$string = mb_convert_encoding($string, "ISO-8859-7", "UTF-8");
$filename = mb_convert_encoding($filename, "ISO-8859-7", "UTF-8");

$path = "test/";

//$dir_handle = @opendir($path) or mkdir("{$path}", 0777, true);

file_put_contents($path."/".$filename."", $string);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I just changed.

ISO-8859-1 to ISO-8859-7 and it is working perfectly now!